# AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher Error

Tags: wcf

I have a setup with a client side application that connects to an IIS hosted WCF service with a load balancer in the middle over SSL.  The following configuration work when I try to use textMessageEncoding.

Server:

```
<binding name="customBinding_IRequestService_gzip2">
 <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
 <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></httpTransport>
</binding>
```

Client:

```
<binding name="customBinding_IRequestService_gzip_secure">
 <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
 <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></httpsTransport>
</binding>
```

However, I want to use binaryMessageEncoding to take advantage of compression, so I change the configuration to this:

Server:

```
<binding name="customBinding_IRequestService_gzip2">
          <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096"
              maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
 <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></httpTransport>
</binding>
```

Client:

```
<binding name="customBinding_IRequestService_gzip_secure">
          <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096"
              maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
 <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></httpsTransport>
</binding>
```

And now I get this error:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The message with To
>   'https://myurl/gzip' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an
>   AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the
>   sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

I tried to incorporate allowInsecureTransport as suggested in some other posts, but the error trail just got worse.  What could be the difference between these two encodings?  Is it possible that I need to change something on the load balancer, or is this just a matter of getting the WCF configuration right?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this suggestion, and it looks like it is working.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2010/04/15/setting-up-wcf-with-a-load-balancer-using-ssl-in-the-middle.aspx